# SQL: Select all movies that belong to all specified genres

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table called Movies:

```
id     |    title                                        |    year
308       Coraline                                            2009
125       Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban            2004
204       Hugo                                                2011
```

and the table Genre:

```
movie_id      |    genre
308                Fantasy
308                Thriller
125                Fantasy
125                Mystery
204                Fantasy 
204                Mystery
204                Drama
```

where movie_id is a foreign key that references the attribute id in the movie table. I am trying to get all the movies that belong to both the Fantasy and Mystery genre (i.e. the output movies should be Harry Potter and Hugo).

I have the following query:

```
SELECT title, year 
FROM Movies, Genre 
WHERE Movies.id=Genre.movie_id AND genre = 'Fantasy' AND genre = 'Mystery';
```

However, I don't get any output from this query and I am not sure why. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Just to make a point: Try to always explicitly join your tables and not use a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do aggregation & use `having` :

```
SELECT m.id, m.title
FROM Movies m INNER JOIN
     Genre g
     ON g.movie_id = m.id
WHERE g.genre IN ('Fantasy', 'Mystery')
GROUP BY m.id, m.title
HAVING COUNT(distinct g.genre) = 2; -- Count of where clause
```